# How to insert an equation within a figure?

Tags: graphics, equations, sidewaysfigure

I'd insert an equation within a figure as shown in the following image.
[image]

I'd like also to visualize the number that identifies the equation.

Is it possible to obtain what I've written?

Comment: The figure is formatted immediately and stored in a savebox.  The equation number will be set then, although the \label (\protected@write) will be delayed until the page where the figure shows up.

Comment: This is virtually the same as [Drawing on an image with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559/5764).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you save the equation in a boxed minipage `\sbox2`, you can `\stackinset` it into the figure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
E=mc^1
\end{equation}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\sbox2{\begin{minipage}{100pt}
\begin{equation}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}}
\stackinset{r}{20pt}{t}{20pt}{\copy2}
  {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}}
\caption{My caption}
\end{figure}
\begin{equation}
E=mc^3
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

At the urging of Don in comments below, I have updated the `stackengine` package so that one may bypass the creation of the intermediate box2.  Instead, one may place the content directly into the `\stackinset` without adverse effects on the `equation` counter.  It should propagate in a few days, I hope.  It is v4.1 2021-07-15

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}[2021-07-15]
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
E=mc^1
\end{equation}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\stackinset{r}{20pt}{t}{20pt}
{\begin{minipage}{100pt}\begin{equation}
 E=mc^2
 \end{equation}\end{minipage}}
{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}}
\caption{My caption}
\end{figure}
\begin{equation}
E=mc^3
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmm, it appears that `\stackinset` typesets its contents 5 times? I thought the whole `\sbox`…`\copy` smelled a bit odd when I saw it, but I thought to try it modified before commenting—is there some compelling reason to keep re-interpretting the argument of `\stackinset`? I haven't had a chance to look at the code yet.

Comment: Ah, looked at the code. It looks like, at the very least, you should have your code save the contents of `#5` and `#6` in boxes rather than macros. It's a lot faster for TeX to do a `\copy\somebox` than to re-parse the tokens from `#5` and `#6` repeatedly. It's kind of expensive to look in graphics files to get the dimensions, not to mention side effects if there are numbered structures in one of the arguments. If you like, I can give you a PR with my suggested changes.

Comment: @DonHosek Thank you for the suggestion, and perhaps I should effect that change.   However, I do seem to recall looking into that sort of thing at one point and someone of repute noted to me that if you load the same `\includegraphics` multiple times, it only goes through the process the first time, and re-uses information for subsequent calls.  Nonetheless, your argument applies even to non-graphical load (such as `\begin{equation}`)s, so I should consider it for that reason alone.  Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: @DonHosek Thanks again for your comment that spurred me on to update the package.  I have just submitted an update (from v4.01 to v4.1) of `stackengine`.  Not only does it only evaluate the arguments but once, both for efficiency and so that counters action in the argument doesn't get out of sync, but I also improved the ability to perform nesting (which was sadly deficient for stacks involving field separators, rather than explicit arguments).  It should distribute in a few days, I suppose.